# Flex Layout styles are getting added automatically when AOT compiler ON not JIT

Tags: angular, css, angular-material2, angular2-aot, angular-flex-layout

In my application using Angular 7, Angular Material & typescript and **FlexLayout** are the latest versions. The problem is FlexLayout styles are getting added automatically when AOT compiler ON not  JIT compiler. When I turned off AOT compiler the styles are not added. Also tried to set flex layout config `FlexLayoutModule.withConfig({addFlexToParent: false});` but it doesn't help.

So, could please explain anyone why it's applying only when AOT ON not in JIT? Or how to remove the automatically added styles?

Answer (score 1):

FlexLayout have a little problem with module injection.

To avoid it with the AOT complilation, you should set all in the same scope:

```
import { FlexLayoutModule, LAYOUT_CONFIG, BREAKPOINT } from '@angular/flex-layout';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    {
      ngModule: FlexLayoutModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: LAYOUT_CONFIG,
          useValue: {
            addFlexToParent: false,
            addOrientationBps: true,
            disableDefaultBps: true,
            disableVendorPrefixes: false,
            serverLoaded: false,
            useColumnBasisZero: true
          }
        },
        {
          provide: BREAKPOINT,
          useValue: CUSTOM_BREAKPOINTS
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  providers: [

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Dont divide the module and the providers, all must be in the same object in imports